# How do I open Windows Explorer in SharePoint Online Document Library new view?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library

How I do get access to windows explorer in the new view of document library

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `"Open with Explorer"` in a SharePoint Online document library **Classic Mode**

- In the SharePoint Online document library, click the Library tab on the ribbon, and then click the `Open with Explorer` icon in the `Connect & Export group.`

Use `"Open with Explorer"` in a SharePoint Online document library **Modern Mode**

- If you don’t have the Library tab, and you're using the new look and navigation experience for document libraries, click the `view menu` (for example, All Documents) in the upper-right corner, and then click `View in File Explorer.`

For more information check [How to use the "Open with Explorer" command to troubleshoot issues in SharePoint Online](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2629108/how-to-use-the-open-with-explorer-command-to-troubleshoot-issues-in-sharepoint-online)

Comment: #1 How do i find it view menu

Comment: The View Menu is the menu on the top right side of the page that says "All Documents"

Answer (score 4):

In order to "Open in File Explorer" you need to be using IE 10 or 11.  I don't believe this works in Chrome, Firefox, or Edge.

Assuming you are using IE 10 or 11 the option can be found by clicking the **All Documents** drop-down from the top right side of the page and you will see **View in File Explorer** below

**Edit:** here is a screenshot

[image]